# Getting empty data for Instagram Ad Campaigns via Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm currently using Facebook Marketing API to get Ad related data of my Facebook and Instagram page. (I have connected my Instagram page to Facebook page)

When I call the below API endpoint, I'm getting data for Facebook and Instagram Ads.

```
/v3.1/ad_account_id/insights?fields=spend,clicks,impressions&breakdowns=publisher_platform
```

When I call the below API endpoint, I'm able to get data from Facebook Campaigns only. I have checked in my Facebook Ad console, I'm able to see that there are active Instagram Ad campaigns.

```
/v3.1/ad_account_id/campaigns?breakdowns=publisher_platform
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Should be rewritten as

```
/v3.1/ad_account_id?fields=campaigns{insights.breakdowns(publisher_platform)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this could also be written as:
`/v8.0/<ad account id>/campaigns?fields=insights.breakdowns(publisher_platform)`

For Insights on ad level I use this:
`/v8.0/<ad account id>/campaigns?fields=created_time,start_time,stop_time,id,name,objective,adlabels,bid_strategy,budget_remaining,daily_budget,lifetime_budget,spend_cap,buying_type,configured_status,effective_status,status,adsets{created_time,id,name,bid_adjustments,bid_amount,bid_constraints,bid_info,bid_strategy,billing_event,budget_remaining,campaign_id,effective_status,status,ads{name,id,created_time,insights.breakdowns(publisher_platform){impressions,reach,spend,clicks,unique_clicks,actions,cost_per_action_type,cost_per_unique_click,cpc,cost_per_inline_post_engagement}}}`